# Subtracting a list of names from a bigger list in R

Tags: r

I have 2 datasets.

A = 3085 rows, 1 column.
B = 527 rows, 1000 columns.

All values in both of these datasets are the names of shapefiles.

I would like to create a new list of A - B[,1]. A.k.a I would like to remove any values from A that appear in the first column of B.

I will eventually be looping this for all 1000 columns.

If anyone can help, it would be much appreciated.

Regards,

Comment: Conversely, is there any way to create a list just of the values that are duplicated in both lists?

Comment: Ah I worked this out, simply by removing the !.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `A` and `B` are `data.frames` or `matrices` you can use such procedure

```
A[!(A[,1] %in% B[,1]), 1]
```

I just now realized fully your question. To loop on all columns of `B` you can use `apply` family function. This call will iterate each column of `B` as `x` parameter and will return list of length equal to the number of columns of `B`, each element of the list will be a vector of mismatched elements of `A` to corresponding column of `B`.

```
apply(B, 2, function(x) A[!(A[,1] %in% x), 1])
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This works well. I replaced the second to last 1 with my looping function and it does the job.

Answer (score 2):

Something simple (but untested):

```
x <- A[, 1]
keep <- seq_along(x)
for(i in seq_along(B))
    keep <- setdiff(keep, which(x[keep] %in% B[, i]))
A[keep, ]
```